# How to Write test-cases for more than one function in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

In my .php file I have more than one function , how I can write test cases for that?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood correctly.
Here is an example:

The class:

```
class Operation
{
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
         return $a+$b;
    }
    public function subtract($a, $b)
    {
         return $a-$b;
    }
    public function divide($a, $b)
    {
         if ($b == 0) {
             return $a / $b;
         }
         throw new \Exception("Dude...don't divide by zero");
    }
}
```

The test

```
class OperationTest
{
     private $operation;
     //this is called before every test. 
     //useful for instantiating the class to test specially when it has dependencies
     protected function setUp()
     {
          $this->operation = new Operation();
     }
     // covers Operation::add()  
     public function testAdd()
     {
         $this->assertEquals(5, $this->operation->add(2,3));
         $this->assertEquals(0, $this->operation->add(2,-2));
         $this->assertEquals(10, $this->operation->add(7,3));
     }
     // covers Operation::subtract()  
     public function testSubtract()
     {
         $this->assertEquals(-1, $this->operation->subtract(2,3));
         $this->assertEquals(4, $this->operation->subtract(2,-2));
         $this->assertEquals(4, $this->operation->subtract(7,3));
     }
     // covers Operation::divide()  
     public function testDivide()
     {
         $this->assertEquals(2, $this->operation->divide(4,2));
         $this->assertEquals(4, $this->operation->add(-8,-2));
     }
     // covers Operation::divide()  when dividing by 0
     // so you can have 2 test methods testing the same class method
     public function testDivideWithException()
     {
         $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
         $this->operation->divide(3, 0);
     }
}
```

COde not testes. Watch out for syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the replay and for the answer. I was looking for the same

Comment: @Marius is it possible to call one test case method from another test case? in magento2 unit test cases

Comment: not sure what you mean. In you want to call `ClassOneTest::testSomething`  inside `ClassTwoTest::testSomethingElse`, I honestly have no idea. I never tried it. But it is totally wrong. Tests should be isolated and not depend on other tests. So don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code for write test case for any Model

create model file or use existing file

```
app/code/Vendor/Testcasedemo/Model/Calculator.php
```

put below code there

```
namespace Vendor\Testcasedemo\Model;

class Calculator {
    /**
     * this function will perform the addition of two numbers
     *
     * @param float $a
     * @param float $b
     * @return float
     */
    Public function addition($a ,$b) {
        return $a + $b;
    }

    /**
     * this function will perform the addition of two numbers
     *
     * @param float $a
     * @param float $b
     * @return float
     */
    Public function substract($a ,$b) {
        return $a - $b;
    }
}
```

create test case file

```
app/code/Vendor/Testcasedemo/Test/Unit/Model
```

put below code there

```
namespace Vendor\Testcasedemo\Test\Unit\Model;

class Calculator extends  \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_desiredResult;
    protected $_actulResult;
    protected $_desiredResult1;
    protected $_actulResult1;
    protected $_calculator;
    /**
     * unset the variables and objects after use
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function tearDown() {

    }

    /**
     * used to set the values to variables or objects.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp() {
        $this->_objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
        $this->_calculator = $this->_objectManager->getObject("Vendor\Testcasedemo\Model\Calculator");
        //can do stuff
    }
    /**
     * this function will perform the addition of two numbers
     *
     * @param float $a
     * @param float $b
     * @return float
     */
    public function testAddition() {
         $this->_actulResult = $this->_calculator->addition(7.0,3.0);
         $this->_desiredResult = 10.0;
         $this->assertEquals($this->_desiredResult, $this->_actulResult);
    }

    public function testSubstract() {
         $this->_actulResult1 = $this->_calculator->substract(7.0,3.0);
         $this->_desiredResult1 = 4.0;
         $this->assertEquals($this->_desiredResult1, $this->_actulResult1);
    }
}
```

As this is just reference code for how to write test case
For more details refer below links

1) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_entities/mtf_testcase.html

2) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/test/testing.html

3) https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-module-magento-2-unit-tests/

4) https://inchoo.net/magento-2/unit-testing-magento-2/